# How to pass array as SELECT params for Laravel Query Builder

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

If I have an AJAX call that returns an array called `$selectArray`, which is `[foo,bar,foobar]`, how do utilize it in a Laravel Query Builder so that it's sanitized? Currently, I have

```php
// Sanitizing Input
// $acceptableSelects is an array of columns in a table. Checks if there are any elements in $selectArray that is invalid
// If the check fails, it return the default array
$sanSelectArray = !array_diff($selectArray, array_keys($accetableSelects)) && count($selectArray) < 8 ? $selectArray : [foo,foo2,foo3]

foreach($sanSelectArray as $ele){
    $query->addSelect('table.' . $ele); // Required since I have a LEFT JOIN
}
```

It seems awfully unintuitive. Either there are better ways sanitizing the input or passing Array as `SELECT` without having multiple `addSelect()` methods, but I can't find any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass an array to the addSelect() method.
e.g.

```
$query->addSelect(['my', 'array', 'of', 'columns']);
```

[Laravel query builder test](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/c85896753f34a964542859bea4cf17ef/php/php8/fdc468877004014cdbe93e848d81e2b6/)